# .htaccess redirect for http to https and www to non-www on a shared godaddy server for all domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

So we recently had to install a 50 domain UCC SSL CERTIFICATE on our Classic Linux Shared Godaddy Server (4GH)...which seems to be running on Apache 2.2. When using the default generic redirect that godaddy gives us in their help articles:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

We would encounter no issues the primary domain on the hosting, however, as soon as one would visit any of the "Hosted Domains/Addon Domains" we were encountering an issue where Apache was including the folder path of said domain in the request_uri ($1) like -- `https://addondomain.com/addondomain/file.html` .

To combat this, I wrote my rules to check for this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule \/(.*\.html)$ https://%1/$1
```

However, this is obviously only ideal in my specific case where the addon domains only sit one folder deep and leads to an html file...you would have to rewrite this if for instance your addon domains were located in `/sites/addonfolders/addondomain/file.php`

We also needed to rewrite all www traffic to non-www, and ran into several issues here as well, such as `http://www.domain.com` getting redirected to `https://domain.com` correctly, but then if you manually entered `https://www.domain.com` it would not properly redirect.

After about 4 days of pounding my head into a wall (sometimes literally), and learning `mod_rewrite`, I have found this to work exactly as intended:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule \/(.*\.html)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,END] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1 [R=301,END] #Don't include $1
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule \/(.*\.html)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301] #Don't include $1
```

It works great now, but is there a better way to accomplish the same effect, that works on GoDaddy 4GH Linux Servers (not cpanel)?

**Edit:**
Ended up just having to use the following on all 50 domains individually:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*(domain.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,END]
```

Comment: Don't mind me for asking, have you contacted GoDaddy support about this? And a way to optimize the `htaccess` is to merge both regexes that use the same condition (there are 2) to 2 conditions and rules only.

Comment: This is something that would fall outside their statement of support for their shared environment...they would tell me something along the lines of "If you need different functionality of your server, you could always switch to our one of our Dedicated Servers"